# Python regular expression to match file-date.txt

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am trying to match file names in the format filename-isodate.txt

```
>>> DATE_NAME_PATTERN = re.compile("((.*)(-[0-9]{8})?)\\.txt")
>>> DATE_NAME_PATTERN.match("myfile-20101019.txt").groups()
('myfile-20101019', 'myfile-20101019', None)
```

However I need to get the filename and -isodate parts in seperate groups.

Any suggestions and/or explainations would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need: `DATE_NAME_PATTERN = re.compile("((.*?)(-[0-9]{8})?)\\.txt")`

.* performs a gready match so the second part is never used.

FYI in my opiniomy you shouldn't use regular expression where normal string manipulation is enough ( simple split() will do ).

Comment: Thanks, change .* to non greed .*? and that works. Should have spotted that!

Answer (score 2):

If you know the filename format will not change, you don't need `re`:

```
filename = 'myfile-20101019.txt'
basename, extension = filename.rsplit('.', 1)
firstpart, date = basename.rsplit('-', 1)


In : firstpart, date, extension
Out: ('myfile', '20101019', 'txt')
```

or just without extension:

```
firstpart, date = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[0].rsplit('-', 1)
# ['myfile', '20101019']
```

Works with more complicated filenames too:

```
filename = 'more.complicated-filename-20101004.txt'
firstpart, date = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[0].rsplit('-', 1)
# ['more.complicated-filename', '20101004']
```

Or, just to split the extension even more nicely:

```
import os

filename = 'more.complicated-filename-20101004.txt'
firstpart, date = os.path.splitext(filename)[0].rsplit('-', 1)
# ['more.complicated-filename', '20101004']
```

Comment: In our situation using re fits better in our situation as we are using lots of regular expressions to match different file name formats. Thanks Anyway

Answer (score 1):

Remove the outermost group and put the `-` between the groups:

```
>>> DATE_NAME_PATTERN = re.compile(r'(.*)-([0-9]{8})?\.txt')
>>> DATE_NAME_PATTERN.match("myfile-20101019.txt").groups()
('myfile', '20101019')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regular expressions for this:

```
import os

basename, extension= os.path.splitext(filename)
namepart, _, isodate= basename.rpartition('-')
```

I'm suggesting `rpartition` since the isodate (as defined in your question) won't 
contain dashes.